# Can I use the adjective 'appropriate" to describe the person? (example below)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, adjectives

Can I say/write the sentence below:

**I thought to bring a German translator with me, but so far, I haven't had much luck finding an *appropriate* person.**

Grammarly's suggestion: I thought to bring a German translator with me, but so far, I am still looking for an appropriate person.

The idea is to express I need a suitable person to do the job. I'm open to your recommendations if you can suggest a better adjective choice.

Comment: The sentence post doesn't indicate *why* the person is appropriate. "Suitable" might be used for social reasons (you have to spend a lot of time with them). Perhaps "appropriate" would be about their particular translation skills, for example they must have a good technical vocabulary.

Comment: Historically speaking, [it was nearly always](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=choose+an+appropriate+person%2Cchoose+a+suitable+person&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) a ***suitable*** person in such contexts - but for no obvious reason, ***appropriate*** has been gaining traction in recent decades. I don't think there's any difference in meaning, apart from the possibility that you might infer the speaker / writer is *younger* if they use ***appropriate***.

Comment: But did you really need to ask, anyway?  I can't avoid noticing that the usage you're *querying* is *I haven't had much luck finding an **appropriate** person*, but when you're explaining what you want it to mean, you quite naturally say *The idea is to express I need a **suitable** person.* Would you have asked this Q with ***appropriate / suitable*** reversed?

Comment: Why do you include the sentence from grammarly? You ask about "appropriate" vs. another adjective, but Grammarly still uses "appropriate". What is the point of including Grammarly's suggestion?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I wanted to show that I researched on my own, plus I wanted to compare native speakers' answers/suggestions to Grammarly's answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not a native English speaker, so I don't feel which adjective sounds natural. That's why I used these two adjectives and was waiting for recommendations/suggestions from native speakers. So far, the best answer I got was provided by you in the previous comment.

Comment: @Codewife_101 Oh, I see. Thanks!